# Menu using ul and li doesn't display correctly in safari

Tags: wordpress, css, safari

I am fairly new to CSS but I have created a menu on the site http://www.peterboroughweddingdjs.com that hovers over the background video.
It is a simple menu using a ul with li and it displays correctly in every single browser I have tried except safari.
In Safari it stacks the menu items like a list rather than in a row like it does in chrome.  This is my CSS for the menu. 
Why is Safari being such a pain?

```
#menu-main-navigation {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex !important;
    float: left:
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to prefix with `-webkit` for Safari's use of flexbox:

```
#menu-main-navigation {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
}
```

Read more on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).